# How to add a custom footer navigation to SP2010 Master Page?

Tags: master-page, navigation, branding, visual-web-part

I'd appreciate any suggestion on how to add a custom footer navigation similar to the one found at http://www.washington.edu to a master page?

The link doesn't have to be automatically generated as long as the user can add/remove links and their heading. Initially I thought I can just use several Summary Link Web Parts and control their position using CSS. But unfortunately Master Pages don't support web part zones.

The only other option I know is to use visual web parts to retrieve the links from a SharePoint list. I'd appreciate just some brief direction on how to implement this using Visual Web Part or any other method.

Cheers,

Ahmed

Comment: You can insert webparts in your MasterPages through the SharePoint Designer interface.

Comment: I see. but Ziga, if a user changes the links in the web part will it show on all the pages that are using the master page or just in that particular page?

Comment: As the webpart is placed on the MasterPage it will of course appear on all pages and sites using this particular masterpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebParts (including SummaryLinkWebPart) are simply classes of type `Control`, so they can be directly added to the masterpage, as Ziga pointed out.

First you'll need to add a `TagPrefix` to the top of your masterpage with the rest of the Tagprefixes to load the appropriate assembly:

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePointPublishingControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Next, you load in SummaryLinkWebPart where you need it:

```
<SharePointPublishingControls:SummaryLinkWebPart runat="server" ID="FooterLinksOne" />
```

See how this works, and look here for more properties that are avilable: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.summarylinkwebpart_members.aspx

One thing I'm thinking of though, is the storage mechanism for the properites (in this case, the links themselves) I believe are stored at the URL level, so it might make this web part useless in this scenario (each page will have to have the properties set manually). *Infact, someone confirm for me please if this only happens inside a WebPartZone?*

Comment: I'd really appreciate it if you could provide me a sample or example or a web page that shows how to do that. Thank you for your help, James.